# Error invalid syntax in pytorch nn module

Tags: python, pytorch

I have an error in my pytorch code, and i really don't understand why.

```
  File "<ipython-input-11-89006c750b74>", line 3
    def GaussianBlur(torch.nn.Module):
                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The rest of the code is here

import torch.nn as nn

```
def GaussianBlur(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, std_dev):
        self.kernel_size = kernel_size
        self.std_dev = std_dev

    def forward(self, img):
        image = np.array(img)
        image_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(image, self.kernel_size, self.std_dev)
        return Image.fromarray(image_blur)
```

Anyone knows what's going on? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`def` is for functions, `class` for classes. This should work :

```
class GaussianBlur(torch.nn.Module):
```